# apache camel read headers using spring dsl

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am trying to read request headers using Apache camel 2.14.1 "Rest" component. Below is my spring dsl to configure rest component

```
<rest path="/a">
            <get uri="/{b}">
                <route>
                    <setBody>
                        <simple>${header.b}:${header.headerName}</simple>
                    </setBody>
                    <to uri="activemq:queue:requestQueue?replyTo=responseQueue"/>
                </route>
            </get>
</rest>
```

When I call this service(http//localhost:8081/test/a/b) by setting the headers (headerName=1) using postman plugin, then my camel configuration is unable to read header values.

As per the documentation, we can read headers using ${in.header.headerName}, which is returning empty in my case.

Please help me to read header values.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing a path `/test/a/b` does not match the path you configured with a base of `/a` and a path pattern of `/{b}`. You have to drop the `/test` from your path.

Why you would not get the headers I don't know. A typo maybe in the header names you try to set/access?

The following works for me, using different styles for accessing the in-headers:

```
<rest path="/header-test">
    <get>
        <route id="header-test">
            <log message="Header: $simple{in.headers[my-header]}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="header-test" />
            <transform>
                <simple>${header.my-header}</simple>
            </transform>
            <log message="Body: $simple{body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="header-test" />
        </route>
    </get>
</rest>
```